# Can we serve diffrent SharePoint Pages Based on their Logins

Tags: 2013, security, login

I want to Create a site where i am trying to build a landing page. On this page if user logs in with AD account it would serve a page with left hand navigation based on what ad group they are part of. But if user doesnt have an ad account i want to serve a read only page or sort of act like Anonymous access of same page.

Can this be done out of the Box.

Comment: I think trying to solve with SharePoint permissions. And would enable anonymous access option for those without AD account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done out of the box.

You need to set permissions (i.e. `Audience`) for navigation nodes, web parts on the landing page, etc. for the desired group(s).

Also enable Anonymous Access for the site/page.

Comment: Thank You for your input, but can we eliminate that whole lefthand navigation placeholder when user is logged in anonymous? I dont want any extra space in left hand side of users, when site is read only?

Comment: @allegrooctopus You can't eliminate it complete. It will still be there, it will just be empty.

Comment: Try using javascript to detect whether the user is anonymous, then hide the Quick Launch. You should be able to use JQuery to change the CSS dynamically.  

http://www.mickyjay.co.uk/blog/?p=129

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/four-ways-add-or-remove-quick-launch-menu-control

Comment: Erin does this apply in sharepoint 2013 too, i searched the the html using google chrome i cant seem to find that anchor with innerhtml 'Welcome'